# Invalid object dbo.UserShoppingItems - Azure IIS & SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

Have created two table '`UserShoppingItems'` & `'UserShoppingBills'` both in Azure database and local database (sqlexpress 2008 r2). I had manually created entity mapping for the tables using dbcontext class (not used ado.net entity database wizard) like `'UserShoppingItem'` and mapping with the following code.

```
"public DbSet<UserShoppingItem> UserShoppingItems {get; set;}"
```

I could see that table exists in both local and azure server, but when I was running the site from azure, got an error message

`Invalid object`'dbo.UserShoppingItems'`and Invalid column name 'ShopId' from 'dbo.UserShoppingBills'`.

The site is built using **asp.net mvc 4 and entity framework 6.1.***. Entity framework has correctly guessed the name of the table but it could not find it. Even I have tested the azure database with my local web server from visual studio, queried the database from SSMS all are working fine except when running the site from azure web server. Please help me identify the bottleneck of the issue.

> EDIT:

```
public class UserShoppingItem
    {
       [Key]     
       [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column(Order=0)]   
       public Int64 UserId { get; set; }
       [Key]
       [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column(Order=1)]
       public Int64 ShopId { get; set; }       
       public int? ItemId { get; set; }        

    }
```

Azure DB Server - Connection string

As I have not used ado.net entity data model wizard to generate entities there is no need for use 
metadata=res://*/xxx.csdl|res://*/xxx.ssdl|res://*/xxx.msl;

```
<add name="xxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxxx_Test;User ID=xxxx@xxxx;Password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Local DB Server - Connection String

```
<add name="xxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpressr2,49454;Initial Catalog=MappedGeoDatabase-Dev;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx"/>
```

Comment: show your connection strings - both for the local and for Azure DB (strip username / password info). Also post the code for UserShoppingItem class.

Comment: @astaykov please find the edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My azure websites are linked with databases. I have two websites in azure one for live and the other for testing. When I have created the test website, I had linked it with live database in azure as I don't have test database that time. I have got this issue because my live database don't have my new tables. Solution: I linked my test site with test db in azure and got its working fine now. Learned a nice lesson that irrelevant to your connection string in web.config file, you need to link your site with appropriate db in azure.

Comment: Is this really a solution? I'm not even quite sure what this is saying.

Comment: Okay, I reread your new info and this has me down a promising path.  So to rephrase what you're saying to make sure I understand it, In the configuration section for an azure website, there's a connection strings section and those values override/take precendence at runtime over the values in the web.config file itself.  My default connection is pointing to an older verison of the database so this makes sense. I can't verify til I get home, but I'm excited about this lead!  Thanks so much!  Article explaining config:  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new information :) lets change the answer.

Are you using the connection string variables in the website config?

This will let you connect both test website and live website to the same database.

Comment: Hi, i have tried the steps that you mentioned previously and nothing worked out. Yes you a right ef is in DAL project and i tried both publish from vs 2012 and manual dep. as well. Thanks

Comment: you did a clean on the DAL project? and then did a rebuild on it too?

Comment: Yes I did Clean build of DAL as well.

Comment: Hey guys do you have any inputs?

Comment: Can you see where it is adding the dbo. Prefix? Try this without dbo. "dbo.UserShoppingBills" or recreate the table as dbo.UserShoppingBills

Comment: updated the answer. you should be able to use the connection string variables in website -> configure to point to any database (even if not liked to your website)